# Nested HTML element not assigning to slot

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom, native-web-component

In the below code I am trying to assign `<span slot='test-slot'>b</span>` to `<slot name='test-slot'>a</slot>` but the assignment does not work. If I bring `<span slot='test-slot'>b</span>` outside of its parent `<div>` container the assignment does take place as expected.

Why is this? Is there anyway you can assign from nested elements with the `slot` element? If not, any alternatives? This is obviously a reduced test case but in my real web component, it is much more intuitive for a user to add an element with the `slot` tag within other containers.

```html
<test-element>
  <div>
    <span slot='test-slot'>b</span>
  </div>
</test-element>

<template id='template-test-element'>
    <slot name='test-slot'>non slotted content</slot>
</template>

<script>
  class TestElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      let template = document.getElementById("template-test-element")
                             .content.cloneNode(true);
      // Initialise shadow root and attach table template
      super() // sets AND return 'this' scope
        .attachShadow({mode:"open"}) // sets AND returns shadowRoot
        .append(template);
    }
  }

  customElements.define('test-element', TestElement);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named slots only accept **top-level** children that have a matching `slot`-attribute.

See this (old) [Polymer explainer](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/shadow-dom#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20only%20top%2Dlevel%20children%20can%20match%20a%20slot.) or [this more recent article](https://javascript.info/slots-composition#:%7E:text=Only%20top%2Dlevel%20children%20may%20have%20slot).

Edit: Not sure where this is coming from though, the spec fails to mention this requirement: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#attr-slot

It also is neither mentioned [here](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#finding-slots-and-slotables) nor [here](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#assigning-slotables-and-slots).